# Remote Xdebug port 9000 busy Phpstorm

Tags: nginx, vagrant, xdebug, phpstorm

i try to debug on a remote vm with vagrant php 5.4 and nginx. When i restart my mac i can set a breakpoint but can not remove it. When i try to halt and restart the vm phpstorm only say port 9000 is busy can not connect.

My Xdebug settings

```
xdebug.collect_includes = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 1
xdebug.dump_globals = 1
xdebug.idekey = ""
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "10.10.21.67"
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug-remote.log
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
```

See you
Al

Comment: So the 9000 port busy was from a vagrant setting
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000, auto_correct: true
But now breakpoints can not be removed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simple try to change the port both in php.ini and in PhpStorm. I also had this info and didn't noticed anything at 9000 port and when I changed in both places (and probably made some restarts) debugging works without any problems. (I've used 10000 port instead)

Comment: No as i wrote it was a wrong vagrantfile setting ;)